# R clump within python with rpy2

Tags: python, r, image-processing, raster, rpy2

My specific issue is exactly the title. I have a large raster processing script in python and need to perform a clump function which I cannot find in gdal / python nor have I figured out how to 'write it' myself.
I am becoming better with python all the time just still newish, but am learning R for this task. (installed R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30))

I am able to get rpy2 installed within python after spending a little time learning R and through help on Stackoverflow I have been able to perform several 'tests' of rpy2.
The most helpful info in getting rpy2 to respond was to establish where your R is within your python session or script. from another Stack answer. As below:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHOME'] = r'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\new_ve_folder\Scripts'
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = r'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\new_ve_folder\Lib\site-packages'
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1'
os.environ['R_USER'] = r'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\new_ve_folder\Lib\site-packages\rpy2'
```

However, the main tests listed in the documentation http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/overview.html  I cannot get to work.

```
import rpy2.robjects.tests
import unittest

# the verbosity level can be increased if needed
tr = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity = 1)
suite = rpy2.robjects.tests.suite()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'suite'
```

However:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
pi = robjects.r['pi']
pi[0]
```

works just fine. as do a few other rpy2.robjects tests I have found. I can create string = ''' f <- functions ect ''' and call those from python.

If i use:

```
python -m 'rpy2.tests'
```

I get the following error.
r\Scripts>python -m 'rpy2.tests'
r\Scripts\python.exe: No module named 'rpy2

Documentation states: On Python 2.6, this should return that all tests were successful. I am using Python 2.7 and I also tried this in Python 3.3.

My script for clump starts as below: 
I do not want to have to actually install the package names each time I run the script as they are already installed in my R Home.
I would like to use my python variables if possible.

I need to figure out why rpy2 does not respond as the documentation indicates, or why I am getting errors. And then after that figure out the correct way to write my clump portion of my python script.

```
packageNames = ('raster', 'rgdal')
if all(rpackages.isinstalled(x) for x in packageNames):
    have_packages = True
else:
   have_packages = False
if not have_packages:
    utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
    utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
    packnames_to_install = [x for x in packageNames if not     rpackages.isinstalled(x)]
    if len(packnames_to_install) > 0:
        utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames_to_install))

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
```

There are several ways I have found to call the raster and clump options from R, however, if I cannot get rpy2 to respond correctly, I am not going to get these to work at all But since several other tests work I am not positive.

```
raster = robjects.r['raster'] 
raster = importr('raster')   
clump = raster.clump
clump = robjects.r.clump
type(raster.clump)

tempDIR = r"C:\Users\script_out\temp"
slope_recode = os.path.join(tempDIR, "step2b_input.img")
outfile = os.path.join(tempDIR, "Rclumpfile.img")

raster.clump(slope_recode, filename=outfile, direction=4, gaps=True, format='HFA', overwrite=True)
```

Which results in a large amount of errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.3/Scripts/new_ve_folder/Scripts/rpy2_practice.py", line 97, in <module>
      raster.clump(slope_recode, filename=outfile, direction=4, gaps=True, format='HFA', overwrite=True)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\new_ve_folder\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 178, in __call__
      return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\new_ve_folder\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 106, in __call__
      res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function 'clump' for signature '"character"'
```

Issues: 
testing rpy2 in command line and script (both produce errors, but I am still able to use basic rpy2

importing the R packages so as not to install them each time

finally getting my clump script called correctly

If I have missed something basic, please point me in the right direction. Thanks all.

Comment: @ Nathan Werth thanks - recode = raster(slope_recode) writeRaster(recode, filename = "newfile2.img", format = "HFA", overwrite = "True")  AND r('recode <- raster("C:\Users\script_out\temp\slope_recode")') using this same r(' <-') format. I think I need a 64bit version of python 2.7 as I am hitting a memory error with RASTER CLUMP.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, replace `suite = rpy2.robjects.tests.suite()` with `suite = rpy2.tests.suite()`.

For your third problem (getting `clump` to work correctly), you need to create a `RasterLayer` object in R using the image. I'm not familiar with the `raster` package, so I can't give you the exact steps.

I will point out the `arcpy` module is *not* "pythonic".  Normally, strings of filenames are just strings in Python. `arcpy` is weird in using plain strings to represent objects like map layers.

In your example, `slope_recode` is just a string. That's why you got the error `unable to find an inherited method for function 'clump' for signature '"character"'`. It means `slope_recode` was passed to R as a character value (which it is), and the `clump` function expects a `RasterLayer` object. It doesn't know how to handle character values.

Comment: Thanks - your suggestion for test still fails on my command line. with same error, 'module' object has no attribute 'suite'...  I am not using arcpy, that is where my python was installed. But you are correct, I have not set a raster in my program, I will work there and try that first, reading a raster with rpy2 in python. Thanks for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I got this all to work with the below code.

```
    import warnings
    os.environ['PATH'] =       os.path.join(scriptPath, 'path\\my_VE\\R\\R-3.4.2\\bin\\x64')
    os.environ['PYTHONHOME'] = os.path.join(scriptPath, 'path\\my_VE\\Scripts\\64bit')
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.path.join(scriptPath, 'path\\my_VE\\Lib\\site-packages')
    os.environ['R_HOME'] =     os.path.join(scriptPath, 'path\\my_VE\\R\\R-3.4.2')
    os.environ['R_USER'] =     os.path.join(scriptPath, 'path\\my_VE\\Scripts\\new_ve_folder\\Scripts\\rpy2')
    #
    import platform
    z = platform.architecture()
    print(z)
    ## above will confirm you are working on 64 bit
    gc.collect()
    ## this code snippit will tell you which library is being Read
    command = 'Rscript'
    cmd = [command, '-e', ".libPaths()"]
    print(cmd)
    x = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    x.wait()

    import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    from rpy2.robjects import r
    import rpy2.interactive.packages
    from rpy2.robjects import lib
    from rpy2.robjects.lib import grid
    # # grab r packages
    print("loading packages from R")
    ## fails at this point with the following error
    ##  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 232.6 Mb when working with large rasters
    rpy2.robjects.packages.importr('raster')
    rpy2.robjects.packages.importr('rgdal')
    rpy2.robjects.packages.importr('sp')
    rpy2.robjects.packages.importr('utils')
    # rpy2.robjects.packages.importr('memory')
    # rpy2.robjects.packages.importr('dplyr')
    rpy2.robjects.packages.importr('data.table')
    grid.activate()
    # set python variables for R code names
    raster = robjects.r['raster']
    writeRaster = robjects.r['writeRaster']
    # setwd = robjects.r['setwd']
    clump = robjects.r['clump']
    # head = robjects.r['head']
    crs = robjects.r['crs']
    dim = robjects.r['dim']
    projInfo = robjects.r['projInfo']
    slope_recode = os.path.join(tempDIR, "_lope_recode.img")
    outfile = os.path.join(tempDIR, "Rclumpfile.img")
    recode = raster(slope_recode)  # this is taking the image and                            reading it into R raster package
    ## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399682/clear-r-memory-using-rpy2
    gc.collect()  # No noticeable effect on memory usage
    time.sleep(2)
    gc.collect()  # Finally, memory usage drops
    R = robjects.r
    R('memory.limit()')
    R('memory.limit(size = 65535)')
    R('memory.limit()')

    print"starting Clump with rpy2"
    clump(recode, filename=outfile, direction=4, gaps="True", format="HFA")

    final = raster(outfile)
            final = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +no_defs")

    print ("clump file created, CRS accurate, next step")
```